# What's the cash penalty for dying?

Tags: saints-row-2

[image: SMOKED! — You got smoked! When you lose all your health, you will be charged a small amount of cash and revived at the hospital.]

<sup>"SMOKED! — You got smoked! When you lose all your health, you will be charged a small amount of cash and revived at the hospital."</sup>
I get the above message after I get revived at the hospital. **How much will death cost you?** Is it fixed or does it scale depending on level, money or another factor?

Answer (score 5):

Every death costs exactly $500. [Source.](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Smoked#Saints_Row_2)